# Resources for text boundary analysis

Tags: text, text-segmentation

I need to do "text boundary analysis" in my project.

I remember there is a resource from google might be a help for doing this job, but I don't quite remember the name or where to download.

I remember this resource is a collective statistic data from google search, it might contains a lot of words that people used as keywords on the search engine.
(Acturally, I am not sure what is in that resource because I read about this article long time ago, but I am sure this resource can be used on finding text boundary.)

Does anyone know about it?

By the way, is there any other resource that might help in text boundary analysis?

(Alex Martelli: I tried ICU and Java, but they can't find words in any one of the Orient languages.)

(dwc : Thanks alot, this might help.)

Answer (score 1):

There's good coverage of the general issue in [this ICU page](http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis) and [this one for Java](http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/text_boundary_analysis_in_java/) but neither refers to the resource you remember, I believe.